# How to create Python extension from existing C++ packages include .dll, .h files using Pybind11?

Tags: c++, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pybind11

I am trying to convert a C/C++ API package into a Python extension. I have gone through [this visual studio tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/working-with-c-cpp-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) succefully. This is a simple tutorial and maybe not very practical for a real convertion.

Here is my task. I have the include folder, a folder of *.dll and *.lib files, and some demo cpp files.

[image][image]

**question 1**: where to place *.dll and *.lib folders?
Following the visual studio tutorial, I created a C++ project. Where can I place the *.dll and *.lib files into the project before **Release and Build** the project?
[image]

**Question 2:** Is there a way to import C++ functions and classed in batch?
To use pybind11, we need to add following code at the bottom of cpp file.

```
namespace py = pybind11;

PYBIND11_MODULE(superfastcode2, m) {
    m.def("fast_tanh2", &tanh_impl, R"pbdoc(
        Compute a hyperbolic tangent of a single argument expressed in radians.
    )pbdoc");
```

Above sample codes are to map "tanh_impl" in cpp to "fast_tanh2" in python module.But I hv many functions and classes in the demo cpp file. Do I have to map them one by one? Can I map them in a batch?

**Questions 3:** which files can I copy to another computer?
I created the setup.py and it can be import from a local conda env. I got many folders in folders' view
[image]
I do not want to re-built one more time on another computer, which files can I copy and move to another computer?

I searched and there are not many detailed examples on pybind11 and VS, so I seek help here.
Thank you ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The dlls will need to be packaged with the python extension (see below) and most likely installed in the same folder.

2) No you need to wrap them individually. This is less effort than it sounds, and even if some sort of batching was available you'd still need to specify them all.

3) This question is about packaging. Your `setup.py` is probably based on [setuptools](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html) which can be used to create [wheels](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#platform-wheels) that can be installed with `pip` without having to rebuild each time. Anaconda also has its own [package management](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/building-conda-packages.html) system.